# Communication fail between Zabbix-Proxy and Server at port 10051 in a k8s cluster with HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, zabbix

I have a communication problem between Zabbix Proxy and Zabbix Server at port 10051. I’m using HAPROXY version 2.0.13. Look my Kubernetes scenario:

[image]

HAPROXY is working fine when I access my website zabbix.domain.com at port 80 and 443.

Zabbix-Proxy has a parameter “Server” that I set with ip address of worker-1 and the communication works fine, but this happen because the traffic don’t pass through HAPROXY server. When I try to set the Server parameter with my domain address zabbix.domain.com that go to my HAPROXY server, the communication dont work, give the impression that HAPROXY cant treat the request.

[image]

zabbix_proxy.conf: Work with Worker-1 ip addr, but dont work with domain name.

The domain name as I said, is pointing to HAPROXY server (10.0.0.110). I think the zabbix-proxy is trying to reach the port 10051 of HAPROXY server and the HAPROXY can’t deal with the requests to forward to my worker node.

This is my HAPROXY configuration, I test with frontend and backend, but now, I just rewrite with Listen parameter.

```
listen zabbix
mode tcp
bind :10051
option forwardfor
server worker-1 10.10.10.112:10051 check
server worker-1 10.10.10.113:10051 check
server worker-1 10.10.10.114:10051 check
```

Someone can help? There are some manner to point to my website zabbix.domain.com, the haproxy treat the request send to my worker-1 in port 10051? Please tell me If need more information.